# How to fetch firebase data by child of child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase database as shown in screenshot, I want to display details of all hospitals by location (Entered by user). Anyone is there who will help me out to solve this problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Hospital").orderByChild("location").equalTo(hospitalLocation);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       String name=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();
       String pin=datas.child("pin").getValue().toString();

   }
 }

  @Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {


  }
});
```

The snapshot is at child `Hospital` then you retrieve the data according to the query [`orderByChild`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#orderByChild(java.lang.String))